# Accessing an elements attribute value directly from the template expression

Tags: angularjs

Given the following Angular template:

```
<div id="MyID" ng-show="MyVar == id"></div>
```

Where I have, **ng-show="MyVar == id"** I'd like to directly reference the element's "id" attribute which has the value of of "MyID". In other words it would resolve like this: **ng-show="MyVar == 'MyID'"**. How can I do this?

Comment: you cant reference DOM attributes directly

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how are you assigning that "MyID". For example , if that id is generated in a controller, you coould use:

```
<div id="{{MyID}}" ng-show="MyVar == MyID"></div>
```

If your id is generated by an `ng-repeat`, you could use the following example:

```
<div id="{{$index}}" ng-show="MyVar == $index"></div>
```

See this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Wulqg0vKyaHbHXwvTZH4?p=preview

If you assign manually your id as you are showing, you could compare it as a string:

```
<div id="MyID" ng-show="MyVar == 'MyID'"></div>
```

Comment: I want to assign it directly in the attribute as it is. In other words I want to reference attribute values.

Comment: And what is the problem with this: <div id="MyID" ng-show="MyVar == 'MyID'"></div>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-init` to achieve this:

```
<div id="{{val}}" ng-show="MyVar == val" ng-init="val = 'abc'">

</div>
```

Here'a  [plunkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/u3LDbvw0N27xnlEgjNjS?p=preview)

Comment: This is closer to an answer, but is there no inline way to access the value of the elements attributes. E.g. ng-show="MyVar == this.attributes[id]" ?